# NodeJS, BlueBird - Wait for Promise to Resolve Before Returning

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, bluebird

I know this sort of defeats the purpose, but I don't see an option.

The setup is this:

- A message handler (function) which will recieve a message to create a RabbitMQ queue
- The handler will create the queue, receiving a queue creation Promise
- The handler then returns a response message indicating completion (of the queue's creation)
- This response message is published over a different queue
- The receiver of the response message begins publishing to the newly created queue

Here's the problem.

I began by not waiting for queue's creation to finalize (the promise to be finalized) and the publisher begins publishing before the queue's creation is complete.

Then I tried using the queue-creation promise fulfillment to trigger the beginning of the publishing.  The problem here is I can't transport the Promise (and it's resolution) across the queue for the publisher to use.

I'm wedged between a Promise and a queue.  If I could force (wait for) the queue-creation to complete, then I'd be fine.

Is this possible?

Comment: Some code of what you have would be very helpful to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Yeah - I'm an idiot.  I was tired - too tired to post code, and too tired to think straight.  The answer is/was to return the promise and hold-off on sending the response until the subscriber promise is fulfilled.  As I said - I'm an idiot...

Comment: What I was thinking, you should do, but was unsure this was a solution. You need to get some sleep when you can't solve a problem. Trust your mind works when you are sleeping and when you wake up you will be able to think more in depth about the problem!

Comment: You can answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah - I'm an idiot. I was tired - too tired to post code, and too tired to think straight.

The answer is/was to return the promise and hold-off on sending the response until the subscriber promise is fulfilled.  Straight-forward promises "stuff".

As I said - I'm an idiot..

Comment: Is someone actually going around and down-voting answers etc from 4 and half years ago?  What is wrong with you?